# Android Options Menu not displaying

Tags: android, menu, android-optionsmenu

I am making a game for Android and the simplest implementation of an Options Menu doesn't work - the game itself is in a seperate class (Engine.java), that extends a LinearLayout, so I am wondering if that is why it is not visible - however the other "top-level" @Overrides like onStop(), onPause(), etc. all fire just fine - is there something I have to do inside my game class to get it to display an options menu?

The code base is from Pro Android Games SpaceBlaster example:
http://www.apress.com/9781430226475
(source can be downloaded)

MyGame.class (entrance point of application):

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    // Set game layout
    view = factory.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    setContentView(view);

    // Enable view key events
    view.setFocusable(true);
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

} //End OnCreate()

  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

res\menu\menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" />
<item android:id="@+id/text"
    android:title="Text" />
<item android:id="@+id/icontext"
    android:title="Icon and text"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" />
</menu>
```

layout\main.xml:

```
<game.thegame.test.Engine 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_absolute"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FF000000">
</game.thegame.test.Engine>
```

Comment: if you add a log statement inside the oncreateoptions method do you see it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a **title** in all your menu items!

Items without a title, I guess, can be displayed in the action bar but not as a list when pressing the menu button. Below is a simple example..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/main_menu" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_undo"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_undo"
      android:title="@string/mb_undo"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:onClick="onPressUndo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, if everything is fine with the code and menu resource files, the reason is not adding additional styles resource directory for a low level API.

Here is my set;

#### AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.levent.learning.notetaker">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

#### A) MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

#### B) Resource File For Menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/hede"
        android:title="@string/hede_item"></item>
</menu>
```

#### C) Resource File : styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Everything seems fine with these right ? But even with these, Options menu is not visible. So I've created and additional values resource directory for API Level 11, named values-v11, and added a additional styles.xml file for that.

## SOLUTION 1

#### D) Resource file for API Level 11

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then it works !

Here is my working configuration, to make two distinct folders for the values resource, I've selected the `Project` option in Android;

[image]

## SOLUTION 2

Remove the following theme definition line from **AndroidManifest.xml** file;

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

So that the new **AndroidManifest.xml** is as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.levent.learning.notetaker">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm a newbie on android development, using **Android Studio** version **2.1.2**. Even this question is seems so old, it is still not obsolete. I hope this answer helps someone out there, cause this problem drove me crazy until I've found the empirical solution, hope that it helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Directly we can add menu items like this , it working fine for me

```
     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
               {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem item1=menu.add(0, 4, 0,"text1");
    item1.setIcon(R.drawable.car);
    MenuItem item2=menu.add(0, 0, 0, "text2");
    item2.setIcon(R.drawable.share);
    MenuItem item3=menu.add(0, 2, 0, "text3");
    item3.setIcon(R.drawable.history);
    MenuItem item4=menu.add(0, 3, 0, "text4");
    item4.setIcon(R.drawable.settings);
    return true;
}
```